# Why is this an Index Scan and not a Index Seek?

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, sql-execution-plan

Here's the query:

```
SELECT      top 100 a.LocationId, b.SearchQuery, b.SearchRank
FROM        dbo.Locations a
INNER JOIN  dbo.LocationCache b ON a.LocationId = b.LocationId
WHERE       a.CountryId = 2
AND         a.Type = 7
```

**Location  Indexes:**

PK_Locations:

> LocationId

IX_Locations_CountryId_Type:

> CountryId, Type

**LocationCache  Indexes:**

PK_LocationCache:

> LocationId

IX_LocationCache_LocationId_SearchQuery_SearchRank:

> LocationId, SearchQuery, SearchRank

**Execution Plan:**

[image]

So it's doing a **Index Seek** on Locations, using the covering index, cool.

But why it is doing a **Index Scan** on the LocationCache covering index?

That covering index has LocationId, SearchQuery, SearchRank in the index (not as "Included columns").

Hover on the index scan:

[image]

This query needs to go in an indexed view served by a SQL Server FTS catalogue, consumed by an autocomplete plugin, so it needs to be 100% optimized.

At the moment that above query is taking 3 seconds. It should be < 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not related but I'm curious, why don't have an order by while using `top 100`

Comment: Out of interest (but not intended to be a fix of any sort) does changing the `INNER JOIN` to `INNER LOOP JOIN` speed things up or slow things down?

Comment: Is your primary keys clustered by any chance?

Comment: It looks as well like your statistics are way off as well

Comment: @Will A I'm guessing by his Actual Number of Rows a nested loop would probably be slower than a merge but it is worth a shot.

Comment: @Will A - what's a LOOP JOIN? That made it instant, and turned the Index Scan into a Index Seek!

Comment: @JStead - statistics on what table? both?

Comment: @JStead - if each iteration of the loop join opts to use a lookup into the covering index it's the number of executions (which should be 100 in that instance) that will matter, I reckon.

Comment: @RPM1984 `INNER LOOP JOIN` forces SQL Server to perform a lookup into the right-hand side table of the join for each row from the left-hand side table (at least, each row on the left-hand side that matches `WHERE` clause criteria etc. - if an index narrows this).  In this case it's forcing the use of your covering index on the `LocationCache` table.  Note that it _also_ forces the order in which tables are joined (rather than leaving this up to the optimizer to determine).

Comment: @Will A - but how is that different to an INNER JOIN?

Comment: @RPM1984 - `INNER JOIN` leaves the picking of the join strategy (LOOP, MERGE, HASH) up to the optimizer - which will be a choice made based on the statistics on the table(s).

Comment: @RPM1984 On at least location cache but I would recommend both tables.  The RDBMS should realize the correct number of rows to do the join on.  I'm guessing because it thought only 1420 it made a bad decision on which type of join it should use.  Join hints can be helpful but can become in appropriate over time.  If stats is properly updated then sql server should always select the best plan.

Comment: @JStead - updating stats on both tables made no diff. @Will A - aggregate your above comments RE LOOP JOIN into an answer and ill accept.

Comment: @RPM1984 - Try your original query again, but insert an extra space between `INNER` and `JOIN` i.e. `INNER  JOIN` (just to avoid picking up a cached query plan).

Comment: @RPM1984 - Am not particularly happy suggesting `INNER LOOP JOIN` as a solution to the problem - whilst it works it's easy to get into a sticky situation if and when the query changes over time.

Comment: @Will A - (relating to the cached query plan suggestion..) is there a way to purge the cached query plan (or plans?)

Comment: @Will A - fair enough. i was also hoping updating the stats would fix the problem, but it didnt. so i don't have much other options, running out of time to get this bad boy live.

Comment: @Pure.Krome - DBCC FREEPROCCACHE will clear all query plans - but I wouldn't advise its use on a live server without specifying one of the additional parameters to limit what's cleared.

Comment: @RPM1984 - is there a foreign key from `LocationCache` to `Location`?  Would a foreign key be appropriate here?  Am just wondering whether adding this might shape the query plan...

Comment: @Will A - yep, there's a FK. Location is the parent, and LocationCache is the child. LocationCache has LocationId as PK/FK, making it a Location 0..1 LocationCache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whilst bearing in mind that it will result in a query that may perform badly as and when additional changes are made to it, using an `INNER LOOP JOIN` should force the covering index to be used on `dbo.LocationCache`.

```
SELECT      top 100 a.LocationId, b.SearchQuery, b.SearchRank
FROM        dbo.Locations a
INNER LOOP JOIN dbo.LocationCache b ON a.LocationId = b.LocationId
WHERE       a.CountryId = 2
AND         a.Type = 7
```

Comment: Turns out i can't use it anyway, as it needs to go into an indexed view (because FTS catalogues need that). but indexed views with a clustered PK cannot have hints. :(

Comment: @Pure.Krome - I hope it was an evil kitten intent on world domination.

Comment: @RPM1984 - darn.  I'll try some alternatives later vs. some mocked up data to reflect your tables and hopefully there'll be an indexed-view-compatible solution.

Comment: appreciate your help! +1 since i didnt mention i required it to be indexed, so this is still a viable non-indexable solution.

Answer (score 40):

It is using an Index Scan primarily because it is also using a Merge Join.  The Merge Join operator requires two input streams that are both sorted in an order that is compatible with the Join conditions.

And it is using the Merge Join operator to realize your INNER JOIN because it believes that that will be faster than the more typical Nested Loop Join operator.  And it is probably right (it usually is), by using the two indexes it has chosen, it has input streams that are both pre-sorted according your join condition (LocationID).  When the input streams are pre-sorted like this, then Merge Joins are almost always faster than the other two (Loop and Hash Joins).

The downside is what you have noticed: it appears to be scanning the whole index in, so how can that be faster if it is reading so many records that may never be used?  The answer is that Scans (because of their sequential nature) can read anywhere from 10 to 100 times as many records/second as seeks.

Now Seeks usually win because they are selective: they only get the rows that you ask for, whereas Scans are non-selective: they must return every row in the range.  But because Scans have a *much* higher read rate, they can frequently beat Seeks as long as the ratio of Discarded Rows to Matching Rows is *lower* than the ratio of Scan rows/sec VS. Seek rows/sec.

Questions?

---

OK, I have been asked to explain the last sentence more:

A "Discarded Row" is one that the the Scan reads (because it has to read everything in the index), but that will be rejected by the Merge Join operator, because it does not have a match on the other side, possibly because the WHERE clause condition has already excluded it.

"Matching Rows" are the ones that it read that are actually matched to something in the Merge Join.  These are the same rows that would have been read by a Seek if the Scan were replaced by a Seek.

You can figure out what there are by looking at the statistics in the Query Plan.  See that huge fat arrow to the left of the Index Scan?  That represents how many rows the optimizer thinks that it will read with the Scan.  The statistics box of the Index Scan that you posted shows the Actual Rows returned is about 5.4M (5,394,402).  This is equal to:

```
TotalScanRows = (MatchingRows + DiscardedRows)
```

(In my terms, anyway).  To get the Matching Rows, look at the "Actual Rows" reported by the Merge Join operator (you may have to take off the TOP 100 to get this accurately).  Once you know this, you can get the Discarded rows by:

```
DiscardedRows = (TotalScanRows - MatchingRows)
```

And now you can calculate the ratio.

Comment: mind == blown (in a bad way). Questions? yep. quote: "ratio of Discarded Rows to Matching Rows is lower than the ratio of Scan rows/sec VS. Seek rows/sec." <- can u please elaborate on this .. and HOW we can use this to check this statistic, etc..

Comment: +1 this is an extremely useful answer.  Having looked at my numbers, it's doing an _Index Scan_ on 400,000 rows but only matching 201 in a _Hash Join_.  Therefore I would guess a _Loop Join_ would be far more efficient based on the ratios.

Comment: your post seems to extremely meaningful. Can you please guide me, how to calculate the ratio **Scan rows/sec** vs ** Seek rows/sec**

Comment: @NandhaKumar There's no simple answer to this and a complete answer is way too much for these comments. Basically it's the difference between the sequential IO throughput (scan) of your disks vs. their random IOs per second (seeks).  That's how we used to calculate it back in the 70's but today there are so many performance enhancements that affect this (RAID, Mirrors, caches at all levels, etc.) that it is difficult to measure and even harder to predict.  I believe that the SQL optimizer assumes some ratio of Seek rows to Scan rows of like 5%-10%.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to update your statistics?

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.LocationCache
```

Here are a couple of good references on what that does and why the query optimizer will choose a scan over a seek.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sqldatabaseengine/thread/82f49db8-0c77-4bce-b26c-1ad0a4af693b

*Summary*

> There are several things to take into
>   consideration here. Firstly, when SQL
>   decides upon the best (good enough)
>   plan to use, it looks at the query,
>   and then also looks at the statistics
>   that it stores about the tables
>   involved.
>
> It then decides if it is more
>   efficient to seek down the index, or
>   scan the whole leaf level of the index
>   (in this case, it involves touching
>   every page in the table, because it is
>   a clustered index) It does this by
>   looking at a number of things.
>   Firstly, it guesses how many
>   rows/pages it will need to scan. This
>   is called the tipping point, and is a
>   lower percentage than you may think.
>   See this great Kimberly Tripp blog
>   http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx
>
> If you are within the limits for the
>   tipping point, it may be because your
>   statistics are out of date, or your
>   index is heavily fragmented.
>
> It is possible to force SQL to seek an
>   index by using the FORCESEEK query
>   hint, but please use this with
>   caution, as generally, providing you
>   keep everything weel maintained, SQL
>   is pretty good at deciding what the
>   most efficient plan will be!!

Answer (score 2):

In Short: You do not have filter on LocationCache, the whole table content should be returned. You have a fully covering index. Index SCAN (once) is the cheapest operation, and query optimizer picks it.

To optimize:
You are joining the whole tables, and later get only top 100 results. I dunno how big are they, but try to subquery the [Locations] table `CountryId, Type` and then join just the result with [LocationCache]. Will be waaaay faster if you have more than 1000 rows there.
Also, try adding some more restrictive filters before joins if possible.

Index Scan:
Since a scan touches every row in the table whether or not it qualifies, the cost is proportional to the total number of rows in the table. Thus, a scan is an efficient strategy if the table is small or if most of the rows qualify for the predicate.

Index Seek:
Since a seek only touches rows that qualify and pages that contain these qualifying rows, the cost is proportional to the number of qualifying rows and pages rather than to the total number of rows in the table.

If there is an index on a table, and if the query is touching a larger amount of data, which means the query is retrieving more than 50 percent or 90 percent of the data, and then optimizer would just scan all the data pages to retrieve the data rows.

[source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/30/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-table-scan/)

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test and came up with the following

```
CREATE TABLE #Locations
(LocationID INT NOT NULL ,
CountryID INT NOT NULL ,
[Type] INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT PK_Locations
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( LocationID ASC )
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LocationsIndex01] ON #Locations
(
    CountryID ASC,
    [Type] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE #LocationCache
(LocationID INT NOT NULL ,
SearchQuery VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
SearchRank INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT PK_LocationCache
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( LocationID ASC )

)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LocationCacheIndex01] ON #LocationCache
(
    LocationID ASC,
    SearchQuery ASC,
    SearchRank ASC
)

INSERT INTO #Locations
SELECT 1,1,1 UNION
SELECT 2,1,4 UNION
SELECT 3,2,7 UNION
SELECT 4,2,7 UNION
SELECT 5,1,1 UNION
SELECT 6,1,4 UNION
SELECT 7,2,7 UNION
SELECT 8,2,7 --UNION

INSERT INTO #LocationCache
SELECT 4,'BlahA',10 UNION
SELECT 3,'BlahB',9 UNION
SELECT 2,'BlahC',8 UNION
SELECT 1,'BlahD',7 UNION
SELECT 8,'BlahE',6 UNION
SELECT 7,'BlahF',5 UNION
SELECT 6,'BlahG',4 UNION
SELECT 5,'BlahH',3 --UNION

SELECT * FROM #Locations
SELECT * FROM #LocationCache

SELECT      top 3 a.LocationId, b.SearchQuery, b.SearchRank
FROM        #Locations a
INNER JOIN  #LocationCache b ON a.LocationId = b.LocationId
WHERE       a.CountryId = 2
AND         a.[Type] = 7

DROP TABLE #Locations
DROP TABLE #LocationCache
```

For me, the query plan shows to seeks with a nested loop inner join. If you run this, do you get both seeks? If you do, then do a test on your system and create a copy of your Locations and LocationCache table and call them say Locations2 and LocationCache2 with all the indexes and copy your data into them. Then try your query hitting the new tables?

Comment: Its probably because you do not have 5.4M rows in your tables.

Comment: lol nice, the reason I mention trying new tables is I had a similar problem a while ago on two tables with 34+ million rows, nothing I did made it work the way it should. But on a dodgy test server it worked fine and fast. After I created new tables and copied the data, it was all happy. I still have no idea what caused the problem, statistics maybe I just don't know.

Comment: What's frustrating .. is when I have the same problem .. and use the UPDATE STATISTICS ... i'm not sure it helps :(