# SqlDataReader does not return all records (3rd attempt)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I've tried to find solution for this problem twice before, but unfortunately those answers haven't provided permanent fix, so here I am, giving it another try.

I have an SQL Server stored procedure that returns list of 1.5 million integer IDs. I am calling this SP from ASP.NET/VB.NET code and executing a SqlDataReader:

```
m_dbSel.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
m_dbSel.CommandText = CstSearch.SQL.SP_RS_SEARCH_EX
oResult = m_dbSel.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
```

Then I am passing that reader to a class constructor to build Generic List(Of Integer). The code is very basic:

```
Public Sub New(i_oDataReader As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader)

    m_aFullIDList = New Generic.List(Of Integer)

    While i_oDataReader.Read
        m_aFullIDList.Add(i_oDataReader.GetInt32(0))
    End While

    m_iTotalNumberOfRecords = m_aFullIDList.Count

End Sub
```

The problem is - this doesn't read all 1.5 million of records, the number is inconsistent, final count could be 500K or 1 million etc. (Most often "magic" number of **524289** records is returned). I've tried using `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` setting when executing command, but the results turned out to be inconsistent as well.

When I am running SP in SSMS, it returns certain number of records almost right away and displays them, but then continues to run for a few seconds more until all 1.5 million records are done - does it have anything to do with this?

***UPDATE***

---

After a while I found that on very-very rare occasions the loop code above does throw an exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnHeader(Int32 i)

So some internal glitch does happen. Also it looks like if I replace

```
While i_oDataReader.Read
  m_aFullIDList.Add(i_oDataReader.GetInt32(0))
End While
```

that deals in Integers with

```
While i_oDataReader.Read
   m_aFullIDList.Add(i_oDataReader(0))
End While
```

that deals in Objects - the code seems to run without a glitch and returns all records.

Go figure.

Comment: Can you post the code where you load the datareader please ?

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk added that. Also very basic stuff.

Comment: If it is a stored procedure, please post the definition of the procedure.

Comment: @granadaCoder it's quite huge, including the definition, multiple parameters of various types, not sure if it matters.

Comment: Are you using any "hints"...like "no (lock)", etc, etc?

Comment: @granadaCoder several queries use "LOOP JOIN". For SP itself I was playing with "WITH RECOMPILE" on and off and that's about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529053/when-should-i-use-an-inner-loop-join-instead-of-an-inner-join

Comment: @granadaCoder yes I know what it is. It's not the problem here. SP runs fine.

Comment: If you select your results into a temp table and select from the temp table inside the sproc, does the problem still occur?

Comment: Can you put a simpler Select in the stored procedure.....and see if you get predictable results? Something like : select top 1500000000 so1.id from master.sys.sysobjects so1 cross join master.sys.sysobjects so2 cross join master.sys.sysobjects so3
/*  select COUNT_BIG(*) from master.sys.sysobjects so1 cross join master.sys.sysobjects so2 cross join master.sys.sysobjects so3  */

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the test, that eliminates problems with SP. I used your query (only limited output to 2500000 to make it faster) and yes with the same result. Occasionally it would read entire set, but often it would get just 1M or below.

Comment: `524288` is an exact power of 2 (`2^19`). Not sure how/if that is relevant.

Comment: @MartinSmith Any idea what that means? and why Reader stops at this point?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - Absolutely none whatsoever. If you remove the `m_aFullIDList.Add(i_oDataReader.GetInt32(0))` and just increment a counter variable do you still see the issue?

Comment: How long does it take before it fails?

Comment: I like where @MartinSmith is going with this: your `List(of Integer)` may be trying to do a dynamic reallocation and failing.  IIRC, these reallocations tend to happen around certain powers of two.

Comment: Right.  I was trying to separate any tsql voodoo from the DotNet code.  I agree, put a counter in, and see if that fails. (and don't add to the generic list as a temp test).

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Sounds feasible but I would have thought that would raise an error?.  Yuriy: `On Error Resume Next` isn't on is it?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885294/list-size-limitation-in-c-sharp       Jon Skeet says "There's a 2GB per-object limit in the CLR even in 64 bits"......and when Jon talks, I listen.

Comment: @granadaCoder - The OP there got up to 134 million items though.

Comment: @granadaCoder Good find!  Note especially the comment from "Brian" to Jon Skeet's answer.  Note also that even in 64bits, there are other possible limits on your process's virtual memory size (available pagefile space, for example).  If this is the problem (i.e., a memory limitation on the `List`) then Martin's suggested test above should reveal it.

Comment: Also consider the possibility of a timeout on the command object

Comment: List<int> test = new List<int>();
            test.Capacity = 2000000000;                 Play with that number......and you'll get the "out of memory" exception earlier in the game.

Comment: @RBarryYoung.  Yeah.  That little conversation explains alot.

Comment: So if I do not "preset" the .Capacity, I get an error at 134,217,728.  If I "preset" the .Capacity ( to .Capacity = 268,000,000; ), it works up to 268,000,000, but if I set the .Capacity to 269,000,000; , it fails on setting the .Capacity.   I would think it varies by machine/ by currently loaded resources.

Comment: @MartinSmith There's no exception-handling in the visible code, so it may be suppressed or lost by the caller.  Also, Memory Allocation failures can be extremely hard for the Framework to catch (because you need to allocate memory to catch an exception..), though that usually results in a Fatal exception and loss of the whole process. As for the 134 million count in the linked answer, note that `134217728 = 2^28` and that an individual process's virtual memory can be limited by other things.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - If the `List` grows by doubling in size every time I agree it seems pretty convincing that this is the problem.

Comment: @Everybody, thanks for the research. Yes it looks like if I remove `List.Add` from the While/Read loop and just increment the counter - it gets the correct count, so it seems to be List issue indeed. Strange thing I didn't get any exceptions (no I don't use ON ERROR RESUME NEXT, but I do have TRY/CATCH block that didn't catch anything). What would be the best workaround? If I pre-set list Capacity (e.g. 2000000) it seems to work - but will it cause any problems (performance, memory usage etc.) ?

Comment: Yuri, can you show us the `Catch` block that didn't catch anything?  Is it written to catch all exceptions, or only certain categories of exceptions?

Comment: @RBarryYoung call to class constructor is inside of TRY/CATCH block and it catches generic `Catch ex As Exception` Exception.

Comment: Can you try it with a `Try .. Catch ..` in the `New(..)` routine itself? Unless it's also getting a `StackAllocationException` (possible but unlikey as a stack frame is much smaller than your List) you really should be able to catch it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Nope, even internal TRY/CATCH block doesn't catch anything. Moreover, I put a conditional breakpoint for "list.count = 524289" and after that reader.read method return False! This what kept me thinking problem was at SQL side. But if I set list.capacity to 2000000 - everything works.

Comment: Hmm, wierd.  Maybe `SqlDataReader` is getting memory allocation failures of its own after that point?

Comment: If it does - it doesn't throw any exception. And how could it be related to List.. weird indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, as we've flogged out in the comments(*), the problem isn't with `SqlDataRead`, the stored procedure, or SQL at al.  Rather, your `List.Add` is failing because it cannot allocate the additional memory for 2^(n+1) items to extend the List and copy your existing 2^n items into.  Most of the time your n=19 (so 524289 items), but sometimes it could be higher.

There are three basic things that you could do about this:

1. Pre-Allocate:  As you've discovered, by pre-allocating you should be able to gwet anywhere from 1.5 to 3 times as many items.  This works best if you know ahead of time how many items you'll have, so I'd recommend either excuting a `SELECT COUNT(*)..` ahead of time, or adding a `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 1)` column and picking it out of the first row returned to pre-allocate the List.  The problem with this approach is that you're still pretty close to your limit and could easily run out of memory in the near future...
2. Re-Configure:  Right now you are only getting at most 2^22 bytes of memory for this, when in theory you shoud be able to get around 2^29-2^30.  That means that something on your machine is preventing you from extending your writeable Virtual Memory limit that high.  Likely causes include the size of your pagefile and competition from other processes (but there are other possibilities).  Fix that and you should have more than enough headroom for this.
3. Streaming:  Do you really need all 1.5 million items in memory at the same time? If not and you can determine which you don't need (or extract the info that you do need) on the fly, then you can solve this problem the same way that `SqlDataReader` does, with streaming.  Just read a row, use it, then lose it and go on to the next row.

Hopefully this helps.

(* -- Thanks, obviously, to @granadaCoder and @MartinSmith)

---

If you really think that the problem rests solely with the List data structure (and *not* that you are just running out of memory), then there are some other ways to work around the List structure's allocation behavior.  One way would be to implement an alternative List class (as `IList(of Integer)`).

Through the interface it would appear the same as List but internally it would have a different allocation scheme, by storing the data in a nested `List(of List(of Integer))`.  Every 1000 items, it would create a new `List(of Integer)`, add it to the parent nested list and then use it to add in the next 1000 items.

The reason that I didn't suggest this before is because, like pre-allocation, this may allow you to get closer to your memory limit, but, if that's the problem, you are still going to run out eventually (just as with pre-allocating) because this limit is too close to the actual number of items that you need (1.5 million).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I do need the full list of IDs, it is used later on in paging mechanism where 50-100 IDs at a time a sent to DB to retrieve full set of data for those IDs only. I do like "Pre-allocate" solution, but I don't want to run an extra query to get record count (and I don't think there's another way to get records affected by Reader). If I preset it to the value I think would be max (e.g. 2000000) - does it allocate that memory right away? What happens if actual number is much lower?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter If you pre-allocate then AFAIK it really does allocate that much.  If you don't want the extra query, the how about the extra column?  That way you can pick it out of the first row.

Comment: I did found where it fails. List reallocates capacity by the power of 2 you were correct, e.g if it has reached 8 records - capacity switched to 16, when reached 16 - to 32 etc. When count reaches 524,288 (2^19) it switches capacity to 1,048,576 (2^20) - and that capacity change works fine, without any error, but immediately after that `Reader.read` return false and exit loop. Any idea how these could be related? I am still trying to find a middle ground between hard-coding the capacity in advance and returning extra data from query

Comment: It's got to be something memory-related under the hood.  But, I'd suggest taking it to Microsoft as it seems like a bug right now (`SqlDataReader`s behavior, that is).

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I should mention that the Debugger could be interacting adversly with all of this also. Memory Allocation failure is such an insidious problem, it can bollix-up all kinds of seemingly unrelated things.

Comment: Can you use a #Temp table on the server to hold the index for paging? Or not store every ID but just the ones needed for the page boundaries?

Comment: @rheitzman IDs are not necessary sequential, I need actual list of IDs for the current page.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I will mark this as an answer, since it did point to the issue and suggested solution, but I am still looking for solution that would not involve returning extra values/queries from the DB or hardcoding list capacity in advance - after all the reason I selected List<T> because of its flexibility

Comment: @Yuri Galanter If you're paging 50-100 items at a time out 1.5 million, you're still doing it wrong.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Tell this to Google search results :) j/k. But 1.5M that's extreme case. Ordinary it is much more manageable list. But I do need to handle the extremes and make sure that record count is correct.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter And Google's primary interface is to first narrow the results via a search filter.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, what a coincidence, that is exactly what my SP does - returns list of IDs for records after search criteria has been applied.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, interesting idea, I was thinking of using different list structure, and implementing custom one maybe the way to go. Side note: if instead of `m_aFullIDList.Add(i_oDataReader.GetInt32(0))` that returns Integer I use m_aFullIDList.Add(i_oDataReader(0)) that returns Object - the loop seems to behave correctly, though I am not sure how stable it is.

Comment: Tried List-of-Lists, getting the same issue. At some point SqlReader just fails.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I think I finally figured it out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18520609/961695

Answer (score 0):

Basically you read all record in SqlDataReader with select query **`I suggest you to add order by in your query`** and it sort all records in Acceding order and they also read in acceding order in SqlDataReader.

I also face this problem in my last project I have read **`more than 2 million records`** from database with unique id serialNo but this records are not come in sequence **`after 1000 records`** it jumps to **`21, 00, 263th record`** and all records are come in wrong sequence.

Then I use **`(order by serialNo)`** this query and my problem is solved you not need to do anything extra only put order by in your select query and it will work for you

I hope this helps for you.