# TSQL Prevent "FAST N" output by default

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

When I execute a TSQL query or a stored procedure that returns large number of records (1M+) by default it begins to display result while query is still executing.

Is there way to prevent this and postpone returning of the result until the query execution is complete?

Comment: Why would you want this? It is possible by storing in a `#temp` table or maybe rewriting the query to get a blocking operator but it then takes server memory storing the whole result set.

Comment: I think this might be causing issue in my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468284/sqldatareader-does-return-all-records-3rd-attempt (maybe I am wrong but it seems .NET code reads only "Fast N" results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a column like the following to the returned dataset, it almost certainly will not be able to do a `FAST(N)`:

```
.., MAX(prevColumn) OVER(PARTITON BY 1) As Dummy, ...
```

Where `prevColumn` is any other column that you are already returning, especially if it's not an indexed column.

Comment: That did it, thanks. Though turned out wasn't needed for my other problem :) but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY or Aggregate function in SELECT will help you.