# Read millions of records from SQL, process them and insert them to another SQL server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[case_waveform_data] (
    [case_id]                INT             NOT NULL,
    [channel_index]          INT             NOT NULL,
    [seconds_between_points] REAL            NOT NULL,
    [last_time_stamp]        DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [value_array]            VARBINARY (MAX) NULL
);
```

This table will contain millions of records. I want to read in data by case_id and channel_index from one database then group 5 minutes worth of them together by decompressing the value_array data and linking them together, compress that stream then add the combined chunk to another database.

The code I have works fine on up about 100k records. After that I get random errors such as out of memory in system.data, CRC does not match on compressed/uncompressd data, invalid character in compressed data. It will happen randomly if I go larger than 100k.

I was using linq to loop through the records but then switched to the SqlDataReader directly. To import the records I use the SqlBulkCopy but I have found I get the error even with that part commented out. It appears that if I write out each combined record to a file as an insert the code will complete but if I start collecting the combined records into a list that I pass over to the SqlBulkCopy for the insert I will get the ranom errors. Most of the time it is an out of memory error on the reader.Read() (or the foreach (var record in records) line when using linq). The memory on the process itself is around 80MB for working set, private and commit.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? IS there a better way to accomplish this? If I use the file I write out it will be up to ~300MB, Can I load a file that size?

Here is the whole function. It has been rewritten about 20 times so there might be some strange code in there:

```
using (LiveORDataContext dc = new LiveORDataContext(LiveORDataManager.ConnectionString))
{
    dc.Log = Console.Out;
    dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    int recordcount = 0;
    // Increase the timeout to 10 minutes for really big cases
    dc.CommandTimeout = 600;
    //Dictionary<int, int> channelindexes = dc.case_waveform_datas.Where(d => d.case_id == livecaseid).GroupBy(d => d.channel_index).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Count());

    // get a distict list of all the channel indexes we need to import for this case
    List<int> channelindexes = (from wd in  dc.case_waveform_datas
                                where wd.case_id == livecaseid
                                group wd by wd.channel_index into grp
                                select grp.Key)
                               .ToList();

    // Loop through each channel's data for the case, combine it and compress it
    foreach (int channel in channelindexes)
    {
        List<case_waveform_data> wavedatalist = new List<case_waveform_data>();
        int warehouserecordcount = 0;
        float secondsbetweenpoints = float.NaN;
        DateTime lastaddedrecordtime = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime previoustime = DateTime.MinValue;
        List<float> wfpoints = new List<float>();

        string queryString = String.Format("SELECT case_id, channel_index, last_time_stamp, seconds_between_points, " +
                                           "value_array FROM case_waveform_data " +
                                           "WHERE case_id = {0} and channel_index = {1} " +
                                           "ORDER BY last_time_stamp", 
            livecaseid, channel);

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(LiveORDataManager.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // Call Read before accessing data. 
            while (reader.Read()) // Currently fails here
            {
                var item = new
                {
                   case_id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                   channel_index = reader.GetInt32(1),
                   last_time_stamp = reader.GetDateTime(2),
                   seconds_between_points = reader.GetFloat(3),
                   value_array = (byte[])reader["value_array"]
                };                    

        //var wdlist = from wfd in dc.case_waveform_datas
        //    where wfd.case_id == livecaseid && wfd.channel_index == channel
        //    orderby wfd.last_time_stamp
        //    select new
        //           {
        //               wfd.case_id,
        //               wfd.channel_index,
        //               wfd.last_time_stamp,
        //               wfd.seconds_between_points,
        //               wfd.value_array
        //           };

        // Loop through each channel and create floating point arrays that are larger than 
        // per second groups.    
        //foreach (var item in wdlist)
        //{
            // Get a record count for the info log
            recordcount++;

            if (float.IsNaN(secondsbetweenpoints))
            {
                secondsbetweenpoints = item.seconds_between_points > 0.0f
                    ? item.seconds_between_points
                    : 0.002f;
            } // assume .002 as a default if this is not set

            if (lastaddedrecordtime == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                lastaddedrecordtime = item.last_time_stamp;
            }
            if (previoustime == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                previoustime = item.last_time_stamp;
            }

            if ((secondsbetweenpoints != item.seconds_between_points && item.seconds_between_points > 0.0f) ||
                item.last_time_stamp > lastaddedrecordtime.AddMinutes(5))
            {
                // The seconds between points has changed so gzip the array of 
                // floats and insert the record.
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(gZipStream, wfpoints.ToArray());
                }

                // add the new combined record to a list that will be bulk inserted every 1000 records
                wavedatalist.Add(
                    //dcwarehouse.case_waveform_datas.InsertOnSubmit(
                    new case_waveform_data
                    {
                        case_id = warehousecaseid,
                        channel_index = channel,
                        seconds_between_points = secondsbetweenpoints,
                        last_time_stamp = previoustime,
                        value_array = ms.ToArray()
                    });
                if (writeFile) { writer.WriteLine("(@caseid, {0}, {1}, '{2}', 0x{3}),", channel, secondsbetweenpoints, previoustime, BitConverter.ToString(ms.ToArray()).Replace("-", string.Empty)); }
                ms.Close();
                wfpoints.Clear();
                secondsbetweenpoints = item.seconds_between_points;
                lastaddedrecordtime = item.last_time_stamp;

                // To keep memory down submit the changes to the warehouse database more often
                // than after the whole channel's data has been prepared. This handles cases
                // that have run for multiple days
                warehouserecordcount++;
                if (warehouserecordcount > 300)
                {
                    BulkInsertAll(wavedatalist);
                    wavedatalist.Clear();
                    warehouserecordcount = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Recordcount: {0}", recordcount);
                }
            }

            // Decompress the float values and append them
            var ms1 = new MemoryStream(item.value_array);
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(ms1, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                // Decompress the float array
                float[] wd = (float[])new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(gZipStream);

                // determine the timestamp of the first float given the timestamp of the last float,
                // the number of elements and the seconds between floats
                var listfirsttimestamp =
                    item.last_time_stamp.AddSeconds((wd.Length - 1) * secondsbetweenpoints * -1);

                // if the last time of the previous list + the seconds between is still 
                // less than the new list's first time then add in NaNs
                while (previoustime.AddSeconds(secondsbetweenpoints) < listfirsttimestamp)
                {
                    wfpoints.Add(float.NaN);
                    previoustime = previoustime.AddSeconds(secondsbetweenpoints);
                }

                // now append the list
                wfpoints.AddRange(wd);
            }
            ms1.Close();
            previoustime = item.last_time_stamp;

        //}
            }

            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
        // If there are any points left for the channel add them here
        if (wfpoints.Any())
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(gZipStream, wfpoints.ToArray());
            }

            wavedatalist.Add(
                new case_waveform_data
                {
                    case_id = warehousecaseid,
                    channel_index = channel,
                    seconds_between_points = secondsbetweenpoints,
                    last_time_stamp = previoustime,
                    value_array = ms.ToArray()
                });
            if (writeFile) { writer.WriteLine("(@caseid, {0}, {1}, '{2}', 0x{3}),", channel, secondsbetweenpoints, previoustime, BitConverter.ToString(ms.ToArray()).Replace("-", string.Empty)); }
            ms.Close();
        }

        if (wavedatalist.Count > 0)
        {
            BulkInsertAll(wavedatalist);
            wavedatalist.Clear();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Recordcount: {0}", recordcount);
    }

    sw.Stop();
    logger.Info("Livecase: [{0}], Warehouse Caseid: [{1}], Recordcount: [{2}]. Waveform data import took [{3}ms]",
        livecaseid, warehousecaseid, recordcount, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

if (writeFile)
{
    writer.Close();
}
```

EDIT:
Here is one of the errors. It happens on this line:

```
 var item = new
               {
                   case_id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                   channel_index = reader.GetInt32(1),
                   last_time_stamp = reader.GetDateTime(2),
                   seconds_between_points = reader.GetFloat(3),
                   value_array = (byte[])reader["value_array"]
               };
```

and here is the stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException - Internal connection fatal error.
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryProcessHeader()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Byte[] buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadPlpBytes(Byte[]& buff, Int32 offst, Int32 len, Int32& totalBytesRead)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
at LiveOR.Data.AccessLayer.LiveORDataManager.ImportWaveformDataLiveToWarehouse(Int32 livecaseid, Int32 warehousecaseid, String backupfilepath) in c:\SRC\LiveOR\LiveOR.Data\LiveORDataManager.cs:line 2416
at VisionSupport.Scheduler.Start() in c:\SRC\LiveOR\VisionSupport\Scheduler.cs:line 90
```

The OutOfMemoryException happens on the above line as well. Here is that stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadPlpBytes(Byte[]& buff, Int32 offst, Int32 len, Int32& totalBytesRead)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
at LiveOR.Data.AccessLayer.LiveORDataManager.ImportWaveformDataLiveToWarehouse(Int32 livecaseid, Int32 warehousecaseid, String backupfilepath) in c:\SRC\LiveOR\LiveOR.Data\LiveORDataManager.cs:line 2419
```

EDIT 2:

Here is another random one. I get these just by rerunning the same code.

Line:

```
float[] wd = (float[])new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(gZipStream);
```

Exception:

```
SerializationException: Binary stream '75' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
```

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
at LiveOR.Data.AccessLayer.LiveORDataManager.ImportWaveformDataLiveToWarehouse(Int32 livecaseid, Int32 warehousecaseid, String backupfilepath) in c:\SRC\LiveOR\LiveOR.Data\LiveORDataManager.cs:line 2516
```

Comment: From my experience, Entity Framework is a must to read datatabase and map to objects. But for bulk insert - it's a must not! It will take forever. Much more efficient will be using ADO.NET ([SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: If you are going to have millions of records, you might want to think of something larger than `ints`.

Comment: And don't use Stopwatch in production code, it won't add you performance. Opposite, actually.

Comment: @gunr2171: System.Int32 can hold 2,147 of millions. Looks ok to me.

Comment: I don't know if this is an option for you, but have you considered doing your ETL in SSIS?

Comment: @gunr2171, an int will hold 2 billion unique values. How does this not work when the count is in the millions? Even for 100s of millions they wouldn't be near the limit.

Comment: @abatishchev Please don't suggest <Technology>. And don't use it. Either you don't know what it is, or just make money consulting for it.

Comment: That said, I don't know that SSIS would be a good fit in this case due to value_array being of type varbinary(max). Generally, SSIS gets its performance through in-memory transformation of the data. This tight coupling of data types is what bites many people in the backside when there's a metadata change in the source or destination. SSIS doesn't just let that slide as it can have an impact to memory allocation. LOB types though, they generally result in a pointer in memory to a temporary file on disk. With SSIS, when you spill to disk, you lose the game.

Comment: @abatishchev A constructive counterpoint looks like the comment left by billinkc

Comment: Nothing is faster than a `datareader`, custom objects, and a `bulk insert` on an app server "close to" the database server.

Comment: Unless it is a SQL error that is an odd line to fail.  Are you sure it is that line?  What is the call stack?

Comment: [value_array] can be null and you are not testing for null.  But that should not give you an out of memory error.

Comment: @abatishchev I've been known to dabble with [SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssis/topusers) ;)

Comment: @abatishchev isnt that the sound a snake makes?

Comment: Are you working at Shazam ? ;)

Comment: @billinkc: Fair point, you won :) In my opinion SSIS as a mess and if you're not already familiar with it it's not an ultimate solution to start using it.

Comment: [value_array] can be null and you are not testing for null.  And that is not an out of memory exception.

Comment: I strongly suspect that what you are seeing is related to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468284/sqldatareader-does-not-return-all-records-3rd-attempt.  Even though it was marked as answered, I was never confidant that we had actually figured it out.  Also, read the comments to the question carefully.  They are long, but very important.  If you asked me today, my bet would be that the SqlReader calls (and in your case SqlBulkCopy) were failing because the `List` allocator was temporarily consuming all of the memory.

Comment: If you say that it works on the first 100k records and then you have `OutOfmemoryException` and you work with large data (binary large objects) you may have been experiencing Large Object Heap fragmentation problems

Comment: In the sample code above, if I comment out the BulkInsertAll(wavedatalist) call the code works. It can populate the list, write to the file. It seems that as soon as I try to write the data to the other database I get a failure ~ 2 out of 3 times. I just ran the code 3 times in a row and it worked with 2.5 million rows now it is throwing the error again. The binary data I have stored is actually small. Just a gziped array of floats (~1000).

Comment: If you think BulkInsertAll is the problem then you should post that code.

Comment: Well, I just found that if I comment out the code that performs the bulk insert I can still get the out of memory exception when i run the function in a loop 5 times. Always happens within 5 tries.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `var ms = new MemoryStream();` in a `using` block

See the documentation on `MemoryStream`

[MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Closes the current stream and releases any resources (such as sockets and file handles) associated with the current stream. Instead
>   of calling this method, ensure that the stream is properly disposed.
>   (Inherited from Stream.)

[Stream.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> You can declare Stream objects within a using block (or Using block in
>   Visual Basic) to ensure that the stream and all of its resources are
>   disposed, or you can explicitly call the Dispose method.

Comment: I wrapped the memoerystreams in using blocks. Did not help with the out of memory exception though.

Comment: It was worth a try.  I would leave the using block in.

Comment: I don't think it will fix the problem but do you really need to hold on to LiveORDataContext dc for the whole process?  I think you could close it after the List<int> channelindexes.  The ToList() will force it to be processed.

Comment: You're right. Once I changed the code to use the SqlDataReader directly I forgot to close up the datacontext. I was using it to loop through the records in one of the previous iterations...

Comment: Check this out GZipStream has some unmanaged resources.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143502(v=vs.110).aspx  Look up catching exceptions from unmanaged.  Test with just a single using gZipStream and resend the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I originally was going to suggest you weren't closing the Reader, but I see the `Close()` now.

There is a lot going on here, and definitely the streams would be the first place to look, but ADO.Net 4.5 has some [new features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/07/15/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta-part-2-examples.aspx) that let you read the data columns sequentially within each row without buffering them, and additionally, let you read a byte array without buffering it in memory.

Might be worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

the easier way is only one way Sqlbulkcopy and reflection with entity framework:

Start with filter data with take and skip in batch of 2000/3000/5000 records;

then  using reflection to get a datatable and pass it to sqlbulkcopy within a transaction and using transaction to prevent issue.

Log each transaction so you will know which record has not been imported in case of fails.

Proceed in that manner on until you have complete your task.It will take a really short time.

Here an example to retrieve a datatable from an entities = take care that the list of object to pass to the following function is Ienumerable so when you have filter your data and used .ToList don forget to call .asEnumerable with statement like this :

```
  Lstads.Select(Function(x) x).AsEnumerable
```

so you may pass to this function the result of your previous query

```
   Public Function EQToDataTable(ByVal parIList As System.Collections.IEnumerable) As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim ret As New System.Data.DataTable()
    Try
        Dim ppi As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo() = Nothing
        If parIList Is Nothing Then Return ret
        For Each itm In parIList
            If ppi Is Nothing Then
                ppi = DirectCast(itm.[GetType](), System.Type).GetProperties()
                For Each pi As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In ppi
                    Dim colType As System.Type = pi.PropertyType

                    If (colType.IsGenericType) AndAlso
                       (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() Is GetType(System.Nullable(Of ))) Then colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()(0)

                    ret.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn(pi.Name, colType))
                Next
            End If
            Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow = ret.NewRow
            For Each pi As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In ppi
                dr(pi.Name) = If(pi.GetValue(itm, Nothing) Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, pi.GetValue(itm, Nothing))
            Next
            ret.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next
        For Each c As System.Data.DataColumn In ret.Columns
            c.ColumnName = c.ColumnName.Replace("_", " ")
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        ret = New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim lg As New EADSCORE.Helpers.CustomLogger(False)
        lg.WriteLog(ex)
    End Try
    Return ret
End Function
```

here an example to use sqlbulkcopy with transaction

```
   Public Sub BulkInserTest(ByVal list As System.Collections.IEnumerable)
    Dim hasElement = False
    For Each el In list
        hasElement = True
        Exit For
    Next
    If hasElement = True Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = EQToDataTable(list)

        Using cnn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BUCLCNN").ConnectionString)
            cnn.Open()
            Using tr As SqlClient.SqlTransaction = cnn.BeginTransaction
                Using sqlbulk As New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(cnn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, tr)
                    With sqlbulk
                        .DestinationTableName = "Ads"
                        .BatchSize = 2500
                        For Each el As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                            If el.ColumnName = "IDAds" Or el.ColumnName = "Province" Or el.ColumnName = "SubCategory" Or el.ColumnName = "AdsComments" Or el.ColumnName = "CarDetails" Or el.ColumnName = "HomeDetails" Or el.ColumnName = "Images" Or el.ColumnName = "Customer" Then
                                //not execute
                            Else
                                Dim map As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(el.ColumnName, el.ColumnName)
                                .ColumnMappings.Add(map)
                            End If
                        Next
                        Try
                            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                                .WriteToServer(dt)
                                tr.Commit()
                            End If
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            tr.Rollback()
                            Dim lg As New EADSCORE.Helpers.CustomLogger(False)
                            lg.WriteLog(ex)
                        End Try
                    End With
                End Using
            End Using
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update Ads Set Article=replace(Article,'&amp;','&');Update Ads Set Title=replace(Article,'&amp;','&')", cnn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End If

End Sub
```

The code above must be modified coz there's some addition filter like if and so on my need but it work as well :)

Enjoy

NOTE: I don't know which are your entity type so you have to check the mapping in order to bge sure that all work fine :)

If it solve your issue please mark it as answer